# Add attributes (sex) to vertex in edgelist

Tags: r, igraph

I have an edgelist of reproductive pairs as follows:

`male_ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), female_ID=c(6,7,8,9,10), a=cbind(male_ID, female_ID)`

using Igraph I generated a graph from the data, to plot and run some analysis on the full df:

`g <- graph_from_data_frame(a)`

My question is, can I now add an attribute (to colour vertices) for the sex of the individual, based on the column they are listed in the edgelist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can assign group labels to your graph object.

For creating the group vector 'sex', your dataframe suggests that you have as many male as female persons. `graph_from_data_frame()` stacks the mal_ID and female_ID columns below each other which you can check with `igraph::V(g)`. Hence you can derive the group vector from that information:

```
male_ID=c(1,2,3,4,5); female_ID=c(6,7,8,9,10); a=cbind(male_ID, female_ID)

#create graph object from dataframe
g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(a)

#investigate structure g
igraph::V(g)
#[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

# create sex group vector
sex <- c(replicate(length(male_ID), "Male"), replicate(length(female_ID), "Female"))

#Check group values
print(igraph::V(g)$group)
# NULL

#assign groups
igraph::V(g)$group <- sex

#Check group values again
print(igraph::V(g)$group)
#[1] "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Female" "Female" "Female" "Female" "Female"

# I use visnetwork to visualise 
vis_g <- visNetwork::toVisNetworkData(g, idToLabel = TRUE) 

visNetwork::visNetwork(
  nodes = vis_g$nodes,
  edges = vis_g$edges
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, but my full db has 900+ of each male & female. Using ifelse, I need to manually add which vertex is which?
Is there a way I can say, if in col1 = male, col2 = female?

Comment: ok, I edited my answer. I just made the creating of the group vector a bit more general, which should work if your full db has the same structure as your example data.